# QGIS: Processing Modeler - Field Calculator uses the input Layer

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to measure horizontal and vertical difference between consecutive points in a layer.

In the following link you can download a WinRar file with 
a shapefile and my model to test in QGIS 3: https://www.mediafire.com/file/hhfmlv4arkd5jx5/KP_test.rar/file

[image]

I can do this in the attribute table with field calculator, using `$x` , `$y` and: `attribute(get_feature_by_id('Layer',@row_number),'x0_kp')`, and: `attribute(get_feature_by_id('Layer',@row_number),'y0_kp')`, then I calculate the differences.

However, when I attempt to do this using the processing modeler the last four columns are NULL. I believe this is because it doesnt really alter the current `Layer` but it works in the memory and then saves the result in an output layer. Therefore when I call `x0_kp` and `y0_kp` they dont actually exist in `Layer`.

I imagine there are at least two solutions for this issue:

1. find a different method to retrieve $x and $y from the next feature.
2. after `$x` and `$y` are calculated, output the temporary results in a `temp_Layer` then call this layer from the Field calculator: `attribute(get_feature_by_id('temp_Layer',@row_number),'x0_kp')`...

But in reality I have failed to make either happen.

---

The automated code from the processing modeler is shown below.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
import processing


class Pins_trials1(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('interpretationpoints', 'Interpretation Points', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('kppoints', 'KP points', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('interpretationlines', 'Interpretation Lines', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Test_kp', 'test_KP', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(4, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Add X/Y fields to KP
        alg_params = {
            'CRS': QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326'),
            'INPUT': parameters['kppoints'],
            'PREFIX': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['AddXyFieldsToKp'] = processing.run('native:addxyfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator x1_kp
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 15,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'x1_kp',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FORMULA': 'attribute(get_feature_by_id(\'Calculated\',@row_number),\'x0_kp\')',
            'INPUT': outputs['AddXyFieldsToKp']['OUTPUT'],
            'NEW_FIELD': True,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculatorX1_kp'] = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Field calculator y1_kp
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 15,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'y1_kp',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FORMULA': 'attribute(get_feature_by_id(\'Calculated\',@row_number),\'y0_kp\')',
            'INPUT': outputs['FieldCalculatorX1_kp']['OUTPUT'],
            'NEW_FIELD': True,
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Test_kp']
        }
        outputs['FieldCalculatorY1_kp'] = processing.run('qgis:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Test_kp'] = outputs['FieldCalculatorY1_kp']['OUTPUT']

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'PINS_trials1'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'PINS_trials1'

    def group(self):
        return 'F'

    def groupId(self):
        return 'Fu'

    def createInstance(self):
        return Pins_trials1()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! I don't know how to recreate the model from the Python script. Can you paste in your post the contents of the model file (_.model3_ extension)? It is an XML file, you can open it with any notepad, and you can save a copy in an "easy to locate" folder from the model builder..

Comment: [link] @GabrielDeLuca https://www.mediafire.com/file/hhfmlv4arkd5jx5/KP_test.rar/file Hi could you please try this link? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the input layer in the expression, use the `@layer` variable.

To access the id of the feature, use the function `$id`.

---

You can calculate the difference between the *x* values of the following id feature and the current feature with the following expression:

```
attribute(
  get_feature_by_id(
    @layer,
    $id + 1),
  'x') - 
attribute(
  $currentfeature,
  'x')
```

---

Note than the `$currentfeature` parameter is not necessary, you can use the `attribute('x')` variant.

---

Here is the model to test the *x* difference:

```
<!DOCTYPE model>
<Option type="Map">
  <Option type="Map" name="children">
    <Option type="Map" name="native:addxyfields_2">
      <Option value="true" type="bool" name="active"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option value="native:addxyfields" type="QString" name="alg_id"/>
      <Option value="Add X/Y fields to KP" type="QString" name="component_description"/>
      <Option value="351.7406720872316" type="double" name="component_pos_x"/>
      <Option value="504.71744827318093" type="double" name="component_pos_y"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option value="native:addxyfields_2" type="QString" name="id"/>
      <Option name="outputs"/>
      <Option value="false" type="bool" name="outputs_collapsed"/>
      <Option value="true" type="bool" name="parameters_collapsed"/>
      <Option type="Map" name="params">
        <Option type="List" name="CRS">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" type="int" name="source"/>
            <Option value="ProjectCrs" type="QString" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="INPUT">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="kppoints" type="QString" name="parameter_name"/>
            <Option value="0" type="int" name="source"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="PREFIX">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" type="int" name="source"/>
            <Option value="" type="QString" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
    <Option type="Map" name="qgis:fieldcalculator_1">
      <Option value="true" type="bool" name="active"/>
      <Option name="alg_config"/>
      <Option value="qgis:fieldcalculator" type="QString" name="alg_id"/>
      <Option value="Field calculator dx" type="QString" name="component_description"/>
      <Option value="526.7406720872316" type="double" name="component_pos_x"/>
      <Option value="623.7174482731809" type="double" name="component_pos_y"/>
      <Option name="dependencies"/>
      <Option value="qgis:fieldcalculator_1" type="QString" name="id"/>
      <Option type="Map" name="outputs">
        <Option type="Map" name="dx">
          <Option value="qgis:fieldcalculator_1" type="QString" name="child_id"/>
          <Option value="dx" type="QString" name="component_description"/>
          <Option value="716.7406720872316" type="double" name="component_pos_x"/>
          <Option value="698.7174482731809" type="double" name="component_pos_y"/>
          <Option type="invalid" name="default_value"/>
          <Option value="false" type="bool" name="mandatory"/>
          <Option value="dx" type="QString" name="name"/>
          <Option value="OUTPUT" type="QString" name="output_name"/>
        </Option>
      </Option>
      <Option value="true" type="bool" name="outputs_collapsed"/>
      <Option value="true" type="bool" name="parameters_collapsed"/>
      <Option type="Map" name="params">
        <Option type="List" name="FIELD_LENGTH">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" type="int" name="source"/>
            <Option value="0" type="int" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="FIELD_NAME">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" type="int" name="source"/>
            <Option value="dx" type="QString" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="FIELD_PRECISION">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" type="int" name="source"/>
            <Option value="0" type="int" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="FIELD_TYPE">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" type="int" name="source"/>
            <Option value="0" type="int" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="FORMULA">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" type="int" name="source"/>
            <Option value="attribute(&#xd;&#xa;  get_feature_by_id(&#xd;&#xa;    @layer,&#xd;&#xa;&#x9;$id + 1),&#xd;&#xa;  'x') - &#xd;&#xa;attribute(&#xd;&#xa;  $currentfeature,&#xd;&#xa;  'x') " type="QString" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="INPUT">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="native:addxyfields_2" type="QString" name="child_id"/>
            <Option value="OUTPUT" type="QString" name="output_name"/>
            <Option value="1" type="int" name="source"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
        <Option type="List" name="NEW_FIELD">
          <Option type="Map">
            <Option value="2" type="int" name="source"/>
            <Option value="true" type="bool" name="static_value"/>
          </Option>
        </Option>
      </Option>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option name="help"/>
  <Option name="modelVariables"/>
  <Option value="" type="QString" name="model_group"/>
  <Option value="difference_against_next_feature_attribute" type="QString" name="model_name"/>
  <Option type="Map" name="parameterDefinitions">
    <Option type="Map" name="kppoints">
      <Option type="List" name="data_types">
        <Option value="0" type="int"/>
      </Option>
      <Option type="invalid" name="default"/>
      <Option value="KP points" type="QString" name="description"/>
      <Option value="0" type="int" name="flags"/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option value="kppoints" type="QString" name="name"/>
      <Option value="vector" type="QString" name="parameter_type"/>
    </Option>
    <Option type="Map" name="qgis:fieldcalculator_1:dx">
      <Option value="true" type="bool" name="create_by_default"/>
      <Option value="-1" type="int" name="data_type"/>
      <Option type="invalid" name="default"/>
      <Option value="dx" type="QString" name="description"/>
      <Option value="0" type="int" name="flags"/>
      <Option name="metadata"/>
      <Option value="qgis:fieldcalculator_1:dx" type="QString" name="name"/>
      <Option value="sink" type="QString" name="parameter_type"/>
      <Option value="true" type="bool" name="supports_non_file_outputs"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
  <Option type="Map" name="parameters">
    <Option type="Map" name="kppoints">
      <Option value="kppoints" type="QString" name="component_description"/>
      <Option value="188" type="double" name="component_pos_x"/>
      <Option value="397" type="double" name="component_pos_y"/>
      <Option value="kppoints" type="QString" name="name"/>
    </Option>
  </Option>
</Option>
```

---

[image: 1]

---

[image: 2]

Comment: It worked well, instead of  ' $currentfeature,'x' '  I used '$x' . thanks!

Comment: [question] @GabrielDeLuca just so I understand better for future processing, the '@layer' variable, what does it represent? when can I use it? it is not in the field calculator list of functions

Comment: When you calculate the X/Y fields, I seen in your model that you use the project CRS, take care than the layer is in the same CRS if you then will use `$x` for the difference. I think that `@layer` variable refers to the parent layer and it depends on the environmet where it is called. I found it in the examples for the `decode_uri` function: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvY2q.png .